# is this regular grammar- S -> 0S0/00?

Tags: grammar

Let L denotes the language generated by the grammar S -> 0S0/00. Which of the following is true?
(A) L = 0+
(B) L is regular but not 0+
(C) L is context free but not regular
(D) L is not context free

HI can anyone explain me how the language represented by the grammar S -> 0S0/00 is regular? I know very well the grammar is context free but not sure how can that be regular?

Answer (score 5):

If you mean the language generated by the grammar

```
S -> 0S0
S -> 00
```

then it should be clear that it is the same language as is generated by

```
S -> 00S
S -> 00
```

which is a left regular grammar, and consequently generates a regular language. (Some people would say that a left regular grammar can only have a single terminal in each production, but it is trivial to create a chain of `aN` productions to produce the same effect.)

It should also be clear that the above differs from

```
S -> 0S
S -> S
```

Answer (score 2):

We know that a language is regular if there exists a DFA (deterministic finite automata) that recogognizes it, or a RE (Regular expression). Either way we can see here that your grammar generates word like : 00, 0000, 000000, 00000000.. etc so it's words that starts and ends with '0' and with an even number of zeroes greater or equal than length two.

Here's a DFA for this grammar
[image]

Also here is a RE (Regular expression) that recognizes the language :

(0)(00)*(0)

Therefore you know this language recognized by this grammar is regular.

(Sorry if terms aren't 100% accurate, i took this class in french so terms might differ a bit) let me know if you have any other questions!

Comment: Can you suggest any book that explain these type of topics and also contain problems to solve

Comment: Sure, here's a very good one that can be found in a PDF format (Michael  Sipser, Introduction to the theory of computation: https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjXyvnHzfTUAhXHyyYKHSRZDtgQFgg8MAM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fgettextbook.download%2FCS%2520181%2FMichael%2520Silpser%2520-%25202013%2520-%2520Introduction%2520to%2520the%2520theory%2520of%2520computation%2520%255B3rd%2520Edition%255D.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFQP4ZXau8z8dDMZBTd4q5iPgFuPw

Answer (score 1):

Consider first the definition of a regular grammar here
https://www.cs.montana.edu/ross/theory/contents/chapter02/green/section05/page04.xhtml

So first we need a set `N` of non terminal symbols (symbols that can be rewritten as a combination of terminal and non-terminal symbols), for our example `N={S}`

Next we need a set `T` of terminal symbols (symbols that cannot be replaced), for our example `T={0}`

Now a set `P` of grammer rules that fit a very specific form (see link), for `L` we see that `P={S->0S0,S->00}`. Both of these rules are of regular form (meaning each non-terminal can be replaced with a terminal, a terminal then a non-terminal, or the empty string, see link for more info). So we have our rules.

Now we just need a starting symbol `X`, we can trivally say that our starting symbol is `S`.

Therefore the tuple `(N={S},T={0},P={S->0S0,S->00},X=S)` fits the requirements to be defined a regular grammar.

Answer (score 1):

We don't need the machinery of regular grammars to answer your question. Just note the possible derivations all look like this:

```
S -> (0 S 0) -> 0 (0 S 0) 0 -> 0 0 (0 S 0) 0 0 -> ... -> 0...0 (0 0) 0...0
                                                         \_ _/       \_ _/
                                                           k           k
```

Here I've added parens ( ) to show the result of the previous expansion of S. These aren't part of the derived string. I.e. we substitute `S` with `0 S 0` `k >= 0` times followed by a single substitution with `00`.

From this is should be easy to see L is the set of strings of `0`'s of length `2k + 2` for some integer `k >= 0`. A shorthand notation for this is

L = { 0<sup>2m</sup> | m >= 1 }

In words: The set of all even length strings of zeros excluding the empty string.

To prove L is regular, all we need is a regular expression for L.  This is easy: (00)<sup>+</sup>.  Or if you prefer, 00(00)<sup>*</sup>.

You might be confused because a small change to the grammar makes its language context free but not regular:

S -> 0S1/01

This is the more complex language { 0<sup>m</sup> 1<sup>m</sup> | m >= 1 }. It's straightforward to show this isn't a regular language using the Pumping Lemma.